# Is it possible to use unlocked weapons and stuff on a higher difficulty?

Tags: resident-evil-2-2019

I'm on my first playthrough on **standard** difficulty, almost finished and I want to know if my unlocked prizes can be used if I start a new game on **hardcore**.

Answer (score 2):

> Resident Evil 2 doesn’t have a typical New Game Plus mode that allows you to
>   carry over weapons, weapon upgrades, and items into a new playthrough. There is,
>   however, a 2nd Run mode that is unlocked after completing the game with either
>   character which mixes up item placements, puzzle solutions, and more, should you
>   be looking for a slightly remixed experience. This doesn’t allow you to carry
>   over weapons and upgrades, though.

[Source](https://twinfinite.net/2019/01/resident-evil-2-new-game-plus-what-need-know/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the text is not clear about higher difficulty

Comment: I think it's quite clear: RE2 doesn't allow you to have your same inventory and start a new playthrough, similar to what other games do with a "new game plus" mode (Borderlands, Torchlight to name a few). Instead, you completely restart the game from scratch; however, beating the game on Leon opens a new mode as Claire and vice-versa. These are called Scenario A and Scenario B (or they were in the original).

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no new game plus mode you can start a new game on any difficulty and any scenario with additional weapons and unlimited ammo.

These additional weapons are unlocked by meeting certain requirements, as listed below:

- Samurai Edge (Handgun) - Complete the game in S Rank or above in Standard Difficult
- LE 5 (Submachine Gun) - Complete the game in S Rank or above in Hardcore Difficulty
- ATM-4 (Rocket Launcher) - Complete the Leon's story (Side A or B) in S+ Rank in Hardcore Difficulty
- Minigun (Minigun) - Complete the Claire's story (Side A or B) in S+ Rank in Hardcore Difficulty
- Infinite Combat Knife (Sub weapon) - Destroy all 15 Mr. Racoon figurines hidden within the game

[Source](https://gamewith.net/residentevil2/article/show/3547)